# AWS DMS service returns different formats of dateTime on target database

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-dms

I am using `AWS DMS` to migrate data from `RDS mysql (Engine 5.6.34)` to `dynamoDB`.

For the first migration, I got datetime data as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ (source RDS 1)`

and the second time, i got datetime data as `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSSSSZ (source RDS 2)`.

Schema and data in both RDS instances are same. Can we specify format during Migration?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
This is because of different engine versions of *replication instances* used.
This **YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ** format comes when using *2.4.2* version .
Version *2.4.3* converts dateTime into this **YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSSSSZ** format.